# How to use comma inside JSON value in dataweave 2.0

Tags: escaping, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a dataweave 2.0 transformation script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  "keyName" : "foo, bar",
  "keyname2" : "foo"
}
```

the outupt is:

```
decrypted payload: {"keyName":"foo","bar","keyName2":"foo"}
```

the comma between quotation marks ruin my JSON structure. I'have tried to add comma as variable, i tried escape it and few other solutions. nothing works.

Comment: The dataweave script works fine for me and outputs: { "keyName": "foo, bar", "keyname2": "foo" }. Is there some other processor modifying the payload after it?

Comment: no. I work on mulesoft 4, anypoint studio 7.3.2. After "transform Message" is Logger. nothing more.

Comment: Can you share full transform and logger config XML?

Comment: ok, it looks like the problem is in java parser while passing payload not as a string

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with your version of DataWeave mapping.

I suggest to check a preview of your mapping. 
It's quite possible, that the error is outside the *Transform Message* component.

[How to use the preview to see the mapping output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmHvl.png)

If this does not solve the issue, you can use [joinBy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-joinby) function to join values, maybe it will help in your case.